# Please review suggested edits!

Tags: discussion

The *Suggested Edits* queue is full for at least the second time in 24 hours.  We need people to review edits!  Until some edits are reviewed, no new edits can be suggested:

[image]

I will gladly begin reviewing edits myself as soon as my site rep is high enough. In the mean time, there's very little *I*, personally, can do. So can some of thei higher rep users please step up?

Comment: I will take a look at them if you give me a few up votes ...

Comment: @StrongBad: I think you're over the threshold now :)

Comment: I feel a little dirty now, especially since the edit queue appears empty ...

Comment: @StrongBad: Interesting, really? I know I still have a number of edits awaiting review.

Comment: @StrongBad: Can you perhaps take a screen shot showing the empty review queue? This might be a bug that needs to be reported.

Comment: @Flimzy StrongBad isn't over the threshold for *tag wiki* edits, only for regular edits.

Comment: @GaëlLaurans I didn't realise that all the edits were tag wiki edits. I am no where close to the 1500 threshold.

Answer (score 3):

Please don't fill up the edit queue ;-) Seriously, we are limited to 20 tag wiki edit reviews per day and per person and I already used up my quota:

> Thank you for reviewing 20 suggested edits today; come back in 3 hours to continue reviewing.

Also, only users with more that 1500 rep points can see *tag wiki* edits and the ones I reviewed still need to be approved by someone else. The only slightly disconcerting thing is that it's not a separate greyed out entry in the review tab, those edits are simply invisible until you reach the threshold but I see them, they are there:

[image: Screenshot with tag wiki edits visible]

For more: [Edit Questions and Answers](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) and [Approve Tag Wiki Edits](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits)

Comment: We appear to have two users with >1500 rep, so all it needs is our second one to go through and review them to unblock a tiny bit of the queue! (Ideally some proper mods would come through and do the rest....)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything to review

[image]

If I go to your profile the suggested edits I see are edits to the tag wiki. If I click on one of them

[image]

so apparently tag wiki edits are not reviewable. I wonder if there is a maximum number of edits you can make in a day (or if I need more rep).

Comment: Meta.SO question [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226744/165502)